# Is there a HTML5 video player that can skip to a movie time on iOS without autoplay?

Tags: ios, html5-video, jwplayer, video.js, mediaelement.js

I know that iOS blocks HTML5 videos from autoplaying without the user pressing a button, which is a pain but OK.

What I need, though, is for JWPlayer, video.js or any player to be able to skip (for example) 30 seconds into the movie on iOS without playing it, so that when the user does press the play button by hand, the movie starts 30 seconds in.

Is there a movie player that makes this possible on iOS?

As a demonstration, I did a test page which is here:
[Javascript Video Test](http://www.stuartbruce.co.uk/editreader/javascript_video_test)
In it, the movies are supposed to skip automatically to shot 3 (marked with a big '3') before playing. It works perfectly in Windows, MacOS, Linux, Android... but not iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Using JW7, Try something like this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 jwplayer('myElement').onReady(function() { jwplayer().seek('10').pause(); });
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding to this. JWPlayer in the end wasn't an option due to network and security requirements so I stopped looking down that avenue. In the end, it seems the answer to my original question was simply "no"- iOS blocks it.